# How to store the runtime mssql error in a variable and continue to run in perl?

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I'm trying to store the runtime mssql error in variable and continue with all other data.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("exec TEST_ABC_DB.dbo.testprocedure");
$sth->execute() ;
my $db_error =$DBI::errstr; #It didn't work also I tried err and state
print "\nDB error $db_error\n";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array( ) ) 
{
      print "Row: @row\n";
}
```

I used the eval block but it is also not working.

My procedure as follows,(sample)

```
CREATE procedure  testprocedure as
select 'one'
select 'three'
select 10/0
select 'five'
```

When I run the script it shows

The output is

```
Row: one
DBD::ODBC::st finish failed: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered. (SQL-22012) at testing.pl line 24.
DBI::db=HASH(0xbe79a0)->disconnect invalidates 1 active statement handle (either destroy statement handles or call finish on them before disconnecting) at testing.pl line 28.
```

Not displaying output even `three`. Displays the only one.

Comment: If you want to do this in procedure itself, you can do exception handling using Try..Catch blocks. See documentation here `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx`

Comment: Do you want to continue with the script with just capturing the errors?

Comment: @AbhiNickz Yes I want to continue the script.

Comment: Look at this [Perl DBI Capturing Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822991/perl-dbi-capturing-errors)

Comment: @AbhiNickz I tried it but it didn't work. Reports the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The PrintError handle attribute tells DBI to call the Perl warn( )
>   function (which typically results in errors being printed to the
>   screen when encountered) and the RaiseError handle attribute (which
>   tells DBI to call the Perl die( ) function upon error, typically
>   causing the script to immediately abort). - [Programming the Perl DBI](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565926998.do)

Therefore you could use below to handle the situation.

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ($die_message) = @_;
    #do something..
};
```

> I'm trying to store the error in variable

In above snippet `$die_message` will contain the error message.

---

Another option would be to set `RaiseError` to 0 and `PrintError` to 1, so that you get the `warn`ings but program doesn't `die`.

> **PrintError**
>
> The PrintError attribute can be used to force errors to generate
>   warnings (using warn) in addition to returning error codes in the
>   normal way. When set "on", any method which results in an error
>   occurring will cause the DBI to effectively do a `warn("$class $method
>   failed: $DBI::errstr")` where `$class` is the driver class and
>   `$method` is the name of the method which failed.
>
> **RaiseError**
>
> The RaiseError attribute can be used to force errors to raise
>   exceptions rather than simply return error codes in the normal way. It
>   is "off" by default. When set "on", any method which results in an
>   error will cause the DBI to effectively do a `die("$class $method
>   failed: $DBI::errstr")`, where `$class` is the driver class and
>   `$method` is the name of the method that failed.

Source - [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintError)

---

You could also do it manually by

```
my $dbh=DBI->connect(....{RaiseError=>1}) or die...
my $sth=$dbh->prepare(...);
{
   local $dbh->{RaiseError} = 0;
   $sth->execute;
   if ($sth->Errstr) {
       # handle the error
   }
}
# $dbh->{RaiseError} is back to normal here
```

Comment: Why not simply switch from `RaiseError` to `PrintError`?

Comment: @Chankeypathak How to prevent the dbi `abort`?

Comment: @mkHun As dgw has mentioned turning off RaiseError and enabling PrintError will prevent the abort.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I got the answer for my question by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440383/how-to-get-the-stored-procedure-result-using-perl/41441486?noredirect=1#comment70098780_41441486) question. I used your trick also. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440383/how-to-get-the-stored-procedure-result-using-perl/41441486?noredirect=1#comment70098780_41441486) answer.

The final answer is

```
do
{ 
while(my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array())
{
    if ($sth->errstr) 
    {
        my $Error = $sth->errstr;   

    }
    print $row[0]."\n\n";
}
} while ($sth->{odbc_more_results});
```