# Return multiple output from stored proc in perl DBI returns extra 0 value

Tags: perl, stored-procedures, dbi

My stored proc returns one output parameter, and along with it it has alot of print statements like below

```
Create Proc
myParam out

begin
  select 'this is a log statement'
  select @myParam = 0
end
```

I am calling the above from a perl script using DBI, for a Sybase server. I am not sure how to get print the value of select print statement as well as myParam?

Here's what I have done

```
$sth = $fdadbh->prepare($db_query) or die "Could not prepare statement: ". $fdadbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or die "Couldnt execute statement: ".$sth->errstr;
do {
      while($row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
         print join("\t\t", @$row), "\n";
      }
  } while ($sth->{syb_more_results});
```

Output I get is
    this is a log statement
    0
    0

If I remove the line `select @myParam = 0` and run it again, I get

```
this is a log statement
0
-1
```

How do I remove that 0 coming additionally. Also, Is there any way of cpturing the outputParam in a variable (apart from traversing and keeping the last value)

Comment: If the duplicate does not help you please tell us and we'll reopen your question. But I'm pretty sure it should be exactly what you need.

Comment: @simbabque So the above prints all of the select statements and the output one after the other. But I see that there is an additional 0 returned after select statement and before theoutput param is printed. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: I don't know. What database are you using? Please [edit] and include the Perl code you are using to fetch. Also show the output as you see it. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @simbabque done. thanks

Comment: It looks like this is not a duplicate after all. I'll reopen. Sorry.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41441486/1331451

Comment: I've asked it in a different manner again.

Comment: That's the one I already closed once. Did it help after all?

Comment: @simbabque It did in parts, I was able to fetch multiple output params and print them as well, but I needed to know how to differentiate between thos outputs as well, hence had to ask a different question. Thanks for your help